# Reading lines from file with different formats c++

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I am trying to read an input file line by line and using `sscanf` to check and extract it. But the lines, although they always have two terms per each, they can be differently formatted, e.g. the file may look like:

```
valueone 0
valuetwo 55
valuethree version
```

Had it been only formats of string followed by number, I could always scan as follows: (`int test;`)

`test = sscanf(line, "%s%f", title, &num)`

but as shown above, sometimes the format of a line is `%s%s` (e.g. 3rd line `sscanf(line, "%s%s", title, strvalue)`), so how can I write the arguments of sscanf to allow for both kinds of line formats?

Comment: If you're using C++, forget about `sscanf` and use C++ features.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen but I am working on a code that is already set up in that way, so I m trying to add this additional feature to it without changing much of the structure/implementation.

Comment: First try to parse with "%s%f" . If you get less than 2 as return value parse with "%s%s" .

Comment: If the second value could be a number or a string, you could to read it as a string and then you can convert to a number (i.e. you need to read it to know what it is).

Comment: @user6556709 thank you, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so how can I write the arguments of sscanf to allow for both kinds of line formats?

You can't, `sscanf` simply cannot do that. What you can do is always use `%s %s` and then try to parse the second string as double using [strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtod) or [strtof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: I like this idea! Next to `strtod`, is there a function to convert `char` to `double`?

Comment: @user929304 Do you mean `char` as a number -128 127 or as a character of a digit 0-9? In the first case `(double)c` and in the second `(double)(c-'0')`.

Comment: I was defining it as `char test[10];` and using `strcpy` to assign to it some value like `"book".` Ultimately, I ended up doing what user user6556709 suggested in comments, namely to split the scan, first check if  `test = sscanf(line, "%s%f", title, &num)` returns the right number, else scanning with the other format. Thanks again,